# Path to private git repository in requirements.txt - how can I make it work with manual setup.py install?

Tags: python, git, pip, gitlab

I have a line in requirements.txt that looks like this:

```
-e git+ssh://git@company.com/company/dependency.git#egg=dependency
```

In our CI, we don't have keys for this server and it's installed in Gitlab via submodules and then `python dependency/setup.py install` is ran manually. This works, but then I cannot run `pip install -r requirements.txt` because it tries to fetch the repository even though it's already installed. Is there a way to mark a certain package as "already installed, don't try to refresh it over git" other than editing requirements.txt?

Comment: Your setup.py file *is* a python file. Off the top of my I don't know if setuptools supports something like this, but if it does not, you can probably add code in setup.py to perform this check for you and act accordingly?

Comment: @idjaw Problem seems to be rather in pip's behavior rather than setuptools.

Comment: Yes. I'm saying that before you run your pip command you can perform the manipulation before hand based on the environment you are in. Your pip command is executed in your setup, so it would take performing preliminary steps before executing that pip.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the dependency's setup.py because the problem is in fetching it. Ideally, I would love to be able to specify some tag in `-e` command that says "this package is called XYZ - if XYZ is already installed, don't update it".

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to get rid of `-e git://` completely, document in README that you expect the user to run `git submodules init && git submodules update` or `git clone --recursive` and use `-e path` instead.